# Making Charts with Named Ranges in VBA

Tags: excel, type-mismatch, vba

I am trying to write some code that will work through the named ranges I have established already in my Excel Workbook.  Each sheet in the workbook has a different layout, which made writing code for the names the lion's share of the work.  I have already done that and now would like to write code that will cycle through the names in each sheet and make charts using the named ranges I have already established.  I have run into a bunch of errors in the following code and would appreciate some assistance fixing them and making the code more efficient!

`ChartName = ActiveSheet.Range(n).Offset(0, -6) & " " & ActiveSheet.Range(n).Offset(0, -5)`

I get an error in the above line for a type mismatch that I just cannot figure out how to deal with.  Also, `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add` draws an invalid property assignment!

```
Sub WEO_DevCharts()

Sheets("WEO").Activate

Dim objChart As ChartObject
Dim n As Name
Dim ChartName As String

For Each n In ActiveSheet.Names

    If n.Name <> "DateRange" Then

    ChartName = ActiveSheet.Range(n).Offset(0, -6) & " " & ActiveSheet.Range(n).Offset(0, -5)

        Set objChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add

        With objChart.Chart
            .chartType = xlXYScatterLines
            .SeriesCollection.Values = n.Value
            .SeriesCollection.XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("DateRange").Value
            .SeriesCollection.Name = ChartName
            .legend.Delete
        End With
    End If
    Next n
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made a number of changes below

*(Updated to handle two separate ranges on the sheet, a range called `DateRange` and one called `Test`. Both ranges are local to the sheet to satisfy the `ActiveSheet` test, else they would belong to the `ActiveWorkbook` {but `DateRange` can be global or local and wil still graph fine either way})*

1. Rather than `ActiveSheet.Range(n).Offset(0, -6)` you need a single cell, probably the first in the `n` range, ie `Range(n).Cells(1).Offset(0, -6)` (plus this means your title lies 6 columns to the left of your range name - ensure there is space)
2. Try adding your chart like `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=500, Width:=300, Top:=50, Height:=400)`
3. Once you have set the xy type you can set your sourcerange directly to your range name `n` then add the `DateRange`range as the x series
4. Add your series name to the first series, ie `.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ChartName` not `.SeriesCollection.Name = ChartName`
5. I have used `InStr(n.Name, "DateRange") = 0` rather than your `n.Name <> "DateRange"` to avoid processing any local name versions of DateRange ie `WEO!DateRange`

I suggest you look at [Jon Peltier's excellent site](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/QuickChartVBA.html#VBAcharts) for further detailed code examples

Sample screenshot of my test code for a local sheet name

- `Test` in `H10:H13`
- `DateRange` in `D14:D17`

[image]

```
    Sub WEO_DevCharts()
    Sheets("WEO").Activate
    Dim objChart As ChartObject
    Dim n As Name
    Dim ChartName As String
    For Each n In ActiveSheet.Names
        If InStr(n.Name, "DateRange") = 0 Then
            ChartName = Range(n).Cells(1).Offset(0, -6) & " " & Range(n).Cells(1).Offset(0, -5)
            Set objChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=500, Width:=300, Top:=50, Height:=400)
            With objChart.Chart
                .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
                .SetSourceData Range(n)
                .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("DateRange")
                .SeriesCollection(1).Name = ChartName
                .Legend.Delete
            End With
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ActiveSheet.Range(n)` or `n.Value`,  use `n.RefersToRange` to get the range the name refers to

Comment: That won't work for updating `ChartName = ActiveSheet.Range(n).Offset(0, -6) & " " & ActiveSheet.Range(n).Offset(0, -5)` as this will return a multi-cell range to the `ChartName` variable